# Identify next 5 available natural / business keys in Oracle OR Using Spring REST API

Tags: java, spring, oracle, rest

How to find next available 10 business / natural keys in Oracle / Java using regular expressions or any other algorithm.
Business Key is 10 digit alpha numeric number. If the value is not 10 digit then prefix with leading zeros.
Example: 00000XYZ123
The solution can be either in Oracle or Java

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle we use sequences for this:

```
create sequence seq_bk;

select lpad('XYZ'||seq_bk.nextval, 10, '0') from dual connect by level <= 10;
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f91ffb76c26d0f2e0256fed3d709f510)</sup>**

This query returns values `000000XYZ1` ... `00000XYZ10`. If you'll run it again you'll get next 10 unique, increasing values.

Comment: Is there any other option in Oracle other than sequences? Can we use regexp?